# Can memory stored variables be read by advanced users on an android app

Tags: android, security, memory

On my android app, I store important processed values in an ArrayList. Can a user with rooted device use a third party tool to read the app's memory to get those values?

Thank you.

Edit: I am talking about class variables.

Comment: You store in arraylist ? and you are saying about memory and root. It does not relate.

Comment: I am asking if the memory for an app can be exposed by a user to read my hidden values. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about SharedPreference or Database or your class variables, be specific.

Comment: Class variables.

Comment: Okay, and you are talking about runtime or by decompiling your code.

Comment: Yes, while the app is running. I want to know if a malicious user can read my variables or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You must assume that your device will be compromised, and someone will be able to read in-memory values.

Especially if you don't want to eventually be sued and you're storing security, financial or medical data.

Comment: I want to know for sure if that is the case. If you could provide me with an article that would be nice. Thank you.